# Proving $\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(3,-4)} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=5$ using $\epsilon, \delta$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

> Prove $$\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(3,-4)} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=5$$ using $\epsilon, \delta$

My try: Given an $\epsilon >0$, we need to find $\delta>0$ such that:
$$\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-5\right|<\varepsilon$$ Whenever $$0<\sqrt{(x-3)^{2}+(y+4)^{2}}<\delta$$

Now we have:
$$\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-5\right|=\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-\sqrt{3^{2}+(-4)^{2}}\right|$$
But i am stuck here?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $0 < \|(x,y) - (3,-4)\|_{2} < \delta_{\varepsilon}$.

Based on such assumption, it results that

\begin{align*}
\left|\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} - 5\right| & = \left|\frac{x^{2} + y^{2} - 25}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} + 5}\right|\\\\
& \leq |x^{2} + y^{2} - 25|\\\\
& = |(x - 3)^{2} + (y + 4)^{2} + 6x - 8y - 50|\\\\
& = |(x - 3)^{2} + (y + 4)^{2} + 6(x - 3) - 8(y + 4)|\\\\
& \leq \delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} + \delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} + 6\delta_{\varepsilon} + 8\delta_{\varepsilon}\\\\
& = 2\delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} + 14\delta_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why twice $\delta_{\epsilon}^2$?

Comment: That is because $|x - 3| < \sqrt{(x - 3)^{2} + (y+4)^{2}} < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Similar reasoning applies to $|y + 4|$. The remaining steps result from the triangle inequality applied repeatedly.

Comment: I know. But you have $ |(x - 3)^{2} + (y + 4)^{2}| $ which is less than $\delta_{\epsilon}^{2}$. So, you are done without considering twice this value. I understand the next steps obtained by triangle inequality

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the observation. Both ways work by the way.

Comment: Yes. Of course both ways work.